# Different scenerios of custom deleter for unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

was reading Nicholai Jossutis, STL book. There is a part like

```
D d;                                           // instance of the deleter type
unique_ptr<int, const D&> p4(new int, D());    // Error: rvalue deleter object
                                               // can’t have reference deleter type
```

I don't understand that, so i created some other scenerios.

Can somebody explain those scenerios why are they working or not?

```
#include <memory>

class C_deleter_functor
{
public:
    void operator()(int* iptr) const
    {
        delete iptr;
    }
};

class deleter_functor
{
public:
    void operator()(int* iptr) 
    {
        delete iptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    C_deleter_functor       d1;
    deleter_functor         d2;
    
    std::unique_ptr<int, const C_deleter_functor&> up1(new int, d1);                  // 1.OK
    std::unique_ptr<int, const deleter_functor&> up2(new int, d2);                    // 2.ERROR
    std::unique_ptr<int, const C_deleter_functor&> up3(new int, C_deleter_functor{}); // 3.ERROR
    std::unique_ptr<int, const deleter_functor&> up4(new int, deleter_functor{});     // 4.ERROR
}
```

Comment: ERROR ERROR ERROR - what errors? Good question should include complete error messages.

Comment: @UPinar `up4` is redefined in your code

Comment: You can expand your code, example of the second one: `const deleter_functor& up2{d2}; d.operator(nullptr);` and you can see that you can't call a non const member of a const referenced instance.

Comment: @273K , no be fair, the OP posted complete code, https://godbolt.org/z/EWerY5hW6

Comment: @alfC Take a look at [mcve] again, you might forget it after 13 years of the signing up. *Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is*

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the book so I don't know the context, but I find it strange that Nico's example would insist on parameterizing the unique_ptr with a reference type.

Most of the problems go away if one uses a non-reference parameter:

```
int main()
{
    C_deleter_functor       d1;
    deleter_functor         d2;
    
    std::unique_ptr<int, C_deleter_functor> up1(new int, d1);                  // 1.OK
    std::unique_ptr<int, deleter_functor> up2(new int, d2);                    // 2.OK
    std::unique_ptr<int, C_deleter_functor> up3(new int, C_deleter_functor{}); // 3.OK
    std::unique_ptr<int, deleter_functor> up4(new int, deleter_functor{});     // 4.OK
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Tb351ocqM

If you put a reference parameter, then you are injecting a reference as a member of `unique_ptr`, which makes things very messy.
Including the fact that a reference cannot store (bind to) an r-value of a newly created object `D()` in Nico's example).

This also brings the conceptual problem of why not copying the deleter.
A deleter shouldn't have too much state in the first place.
At least to the point that one is trying to prevent a copy of it.
Let alone also have *mutable* state (as in your second class).

This is what I don't like about "pure" C++ books, C++ in the abstract.
Authors try to corner you into odd cases without looking at the big picture.
And, of course, after cornering you, they come up with a "smart" workaround that needs the knowledge of a nitty-gritty detail of the language; instead of questioning why you are in such a corner in the first place.

Avoiding copies (like in this case) at all costs, when they are perfectly reasonable and efficient produces the majority of these corner cases.

Answer (score 1):

### First and foremost

Note that while having a reference type as a deleter in a `unique_ptr` is possible, the usability of such pointers is limited because their lifetime can't extend over the lifetime of the actual object of the deleter. You could however use that for eg. global objects.

### The first error:

```
std::unique_ptr<int, const deleter_functor&> up2(new int, d2);
```

You are injecting a const reference to `deleter_functor` to the `unique_ptr` (OK) and initialize it from a nonconst lvalue (OK), but when the lifetime terminates, the unique ptr would call something like `deleter.operator()(ptr)` which fails because `deleter` is reference to `const` and its `operator()` is nonconst.

### The second error:

```
std::unique_ptr<int, const C_deleter_functor&> up3(new int, C_deleter_functor{});
```

You are basically trying to initialize a `const` reference from a temporary. That can't go well (except in case of function parameter, but here you're trying to retain the reference inside an object).

### The third error:

```
std::unique_ptr<int, const deleter_functor&> up4(new int, deleter_functor{});
```

This basically fuses the aforementioned problems into one line.